# How to get new cards/decks?

Tags: scrolls

I bought Scrolls and I just tried to play the tutorial first and a match against CPU, but at the moment I didn't receive any gems or coins, that I suppose are used to get new cards at the store.

So my question is simple, how can I get new cards for free playing Scrolls? I read some months ago in an interview that all cards in the game could be get for free just playing, is it still true at the release?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, you get gold just by playing and all cards are obtainable just by playing.**

In single-player:

- You get gold by playing a quick match (both winning and losing).
- You get no gold for the tutorial match.
- You get gold once for each trial you *win*. Repeated trials give nothing.

In multiplayer you also get gold both for winning and losing a match. For details you can check the [wiki](http://www.scrollsguide.com/wiki/index.php/Gold).

Shards can only be bought with real money and can be used to:

- Unlock the other starter decks.
- Buy the weekly face-up offers. These are six random scrolls (2 common, 2 uncommon and 2 rare) that refresh weekly just for you.

Shards can not buy anything that can't be bought with gold, and to buy random scrolls and scroll packs (which is the primary way to get new scrolls) you can only use gold.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. You said that to unlock the other starter decks you need to use gems that can be bought only with real money. Are there other possibilities to unlock starter decks other than this?

Comment: Yes, you can unlock them with gold as well. To clarify, you can buy _every_ item in the shop with gold. A few items can be payed with gems _and_ gold.

Answer (score 0):

You get coins playing against other players. You can use these coins to purchase cards. It will take a long time to build up a sizeable collection.

Comment: Have you tested this in the release version?

Comment: Have I personally ground enough out coins to get every scroll? No.

Comment: Sorry, I just meant had you tried it since it came out of beta. I wasn't sure if they'd changed anything.